# local memory visibility with volatile write

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

As I understood new java memory model mandates that access to volatile variables is not reordered with access to other variables and thus following [code](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/) is correct:

```
Map configOptions;
char[] configText;
volatile boolean initialized = false;

// In Thread A
configOptions = new HashMap();
configText = readConfigFile(fileName);
processConfigOptions(configText, configOptions);
initialized = true;

// In Thread B
while (!initialized) 
  sleep();
// use configOptions
```

so when `initialized` is set to `true` config options is already initialized, but is it visible? I mean is it already in main memory?

Comment: Even if it will work, making `configOptions`'s visibility dependent on another variable's is extremely fragile. You should avoid whenever possible: a) sequential semantics ("X is valid because it happens before Y") and b) coupling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. As of Java 5 accessing a volatile variable creates a memory barrier that effectively ***synchronizes copies of all cached variables*** with the main memory.

This is known as *Synchronization Piggybacking* where a write on a non-synchronized variable uses subsequent synchronization on some other variable to update its value with the main memory.

Also, read/write on a volatile is expensive. It's not recommended to make use of it to bail out of an infinite loop. If it's somehow unavoidable at least make use of a `Thread.sleep()` somewhere.

*References:*
[Volatile piggyback. Is this enough for visiblity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769570/volatile-piggyback-is-this-enough-for-visiblity)

Answer (score 1):

> so when initialized is set to true config options is already initialized, but is it visible?

**Yes** . As soon you made it `volatile` is visible to all thread and read from `main memory`
As per [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)

> The Java programming language allows threads to access shared variables (§17.1). As a rule, to ensure that shared variables are consistently and reliably updated, a thread should ensure that it has exclusive use of such variables by obtaining a lock that, conventionally, enforces mutual exclusion for those shared variables. 
>   A field may be declared volatile, in which case the Java Memory Model ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable (§17.4). `

Comment: `configOptions` is not volatile, only `initialized` is volatile

Comment: Read operation on `initialized ` will be taken from main memory not `configOptions ' threads will read `configOptions` from their local cache

Comment: All threads will see latest update of `initialized ` because this is volatile.

Comment: Question is not about `initialized` variable, but about `configOptions`