# Java volatile and construction objects

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

I need some memory model advice.

As we know `volatile write` and subsequent `volatile read` have happens-before relationships. Also we know that constructors are not synchronized and there is no hb between constructor returns and using fields initialization (except final fields). Now consider the following code:

```
public class MyClass{
    public volatile String str1;
    public volatile String str2;

    public MyClass(String str1, String str2){
        this.str1 = str1;
        this.str2 = str2;
    }

    public void use(){
        System.out.println(str1 + str2);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
public volatile MyClass mc = null;

Thread(() -> {
    mc = new MyClass("str1", "str2"));
}).start();

Thread(() -> {
    If(mc != null)
       mc.use;       //Is it guaranteed that str1str2 will be printed if we get here?
}).start();
```

Is it guaranteed that if the thread discovers `mc != null` then `str1str2` will always be printed?

I think it ***is guaranteed*** by the JMM because here in `mc = new MyClass("str1", "str2"));` writing to mc and writing to `str1` and `str2` are in happens-before relationship. This is because writing to `str1`/`str2` are performed according to [inter-thread semantic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3) so they are in program order. So we have writing to `mc` ***hb*** reading `mc` so "str1str2" will always be printed.

Also if we make fields `str1`/`str2` ***non-volatile*** there will be no such guarantee anymore.

Is my judgement correct? Can you please expand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If Thread B wishes to see changes Thread A makes, can only the last change be to a volatile variable as opposed to all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52509663/5221149)

Comment: Even if `str1` and `str2` were not `volatile`, the simple fact of `mc` being `volatile` means that output will always be "str1str2", if there is any output at all. See answer in link above for why.

Comment: @Andreas Not quite clear how you imply this. Let me try to go step by step. There is a `hb` writing to a volatile and subsequent read from volatile. But there is no hb between writing to `str2` in constructor and writing to `mc`.

Comment: Sure there is: *"If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y)"* --- So `hb( this.str1 = str1 , mc = new MyClass )`, and `volatile` ensures that `hb( mc = new MyClass , mc.use() )`, and you also have `hb( mc.use() , println(str1 + str2) )`, which means `hb( this.str1 = str1 , println(str1 + str2) )`, exactly the same sequence of events as in the duplicate.

Comment: @Andreas thanks, understood.

Comment: The point is that mc will only != null when the constructor has successfuly finished.